# AJAX Post is sending only partial rows PHP

Tags: javascript, php, excel, ajax

AJAX Post is sending only partial rows PHP.
This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "code.php",
    data: {"excelRows":excelRows},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("fail");
    }
});
    }
```

excelRows contains 39 rows, but I am getting only 25 rows to PHP.
Here is my PHP script -

```
$answer = $_POST ['excelRows'];
```

Comment: I have aslo updated max_input_vars = 10000 in /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini file.

Comment: Can you share the sample data

Comment: it has nothing to do with max_input_vars

Comment: The sample data contains details of insurance policies, and some of the fields can be empty. It's confidential data, do you need any specific info in sample data?

Comment: Well, some representative data would be helpful, so we can see, whether there might be problems with the format or lengths. Obviously nobody is interested in "real" data.

Comment: @Pavani As you are getting partial data, your ajax is working fine. But as you are saying only 25 rows,  sample data will help us to see if something is getting broken bcz of the data

Comment: Here is the sample data:

Policy Number Name Of The Insured Name Of The Self Member Relationship Card Number/UHID Member Reference No. Sum Assured Category Of Claim AL-Inward Number AL-Inward Date AL-Number
40/759/00/0 ram KADAMBINI WIFE IL1600 698 250000 REIMBURSEMENT   
40/759/00/000 SUCHITA SUCHITA  SELF IL1640 1139 150000 REIMBURSEMENT   
40/759/00/0 NAGI REDDY  NAGI REDDY  SELF IL16406 182 250000 CASHLESS AL-002515541 3 Sep 18 110200798500

Comment: When I am printing the data from PHP, the output is as below-
Array
( [0] => Array
        ( [Policy Number] => 4016/152/00/000
[Name Of The Insured] => RAM
[Name Of The Self Member] => KADAMBINI
[Relationship] => WIFE
[Category Of Claim] => REIMBURSEMENT
            [Claim-Hospital Name] => Nizams Institute
            [Type Of Claim] => FRESH CLAIM
            [Claim Number] => 2.2022E+11
            [__EMPTY] => Other
            [Claim-Final Diagnosis] => leukaemia
            [Claim-Disallowed Reasons] => ~~~gate pass~diapers
        )
[1] => Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample AJAX-call with the data you provided. So far everything works OK. Maybe you should try it out again with your original data and closely watch *where* it stops working. This might give you a clue as to what needs fixing ...

In the following sample code I sent the data in a "multiplied form" (ending up as an array with 48 elements). If I double it again it would lead to a failed AJAX call. This might be caused by the receiving end accepting only input up to a certain length. Needs to be further investigated (no time at the moment).

```js
const excelrows={
    "Sheet1": [
        {
            "Policy Number": "4106/151212/00/000",
            "Name Of The Insured": "RAM",
            "Name Of The Self Member": "KADAMBINI",
            "Relationship": "WIFE",
            "Card Number/UHID": "IL1666",
            "Member Reference No.": "444",
            "Sum Assured": "5455",
            "Category Of Claim": "REIMBURSEMENT",
            "Claim-Hospital Name": "OMNI Hospitals",
            "Type Of Claim": "FRESH CLAIM",
            "Claim-Inward Number": "CL-0123",
            "Claim-Inward Date": "29 Sep 18",
            "Claim Number": "278656",
            "undefined": "Other",
            "Claim-Final Diagnosis": "Myeloid leukaemia~Other septicaemia",
            "Claim-Documents Received Date": "28 Sep 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Admission": "2 Aug 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Discharge": "17 Aug 18",
            "Claim-Status": "APPROVED AND PAID",
            "Claim-Date Of Approval": "11/5/2018",
            "Days": "38",
            "Claim-Amount Claimed": "187765",
            "Claim-Sanctioned Amount": "420",
            "Claim-Disallowed Amount": "~~~gate pass~diapers",
            "Claim-Co-Payment Deduction": "FT",
            "Payment Mode": "5 Nov 18",
            "Claim-Cheque Date": "UYYY",
            "Claim-Cheque Number": "0",
            "Service Tax Rate": "888888",
            "TDS Rate": "0",
            "Claim-Service Tax Amt": "193399",
            "Batch-Service Tax Amt": "15 Oct 18",
            "Batch-TDS Amt": "23 Oct 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Query Revert": "N"
        },
        {
            "Policy Number": "4106/151212/00/000",
            "Name Of The Insured": "SUCHITA",
            "Name Of The Self Member": "SELF",
            "Relationship": "IL1640",
            "Card Number/UHID": "1342",
            "Member Reference No.": "333333",
            "Sum Assured": "REIMBURSEMENT",
            "AL-Copay Deduction": "Maxcure",
            "Claim-Hospital Name": "FRESH CLAIM",
            "Type Of Claim": "CL-09989",
            "Claim-Inward Number": "21 Nov 18",
            "Claim-Inward Date": "27865566",
            "Claim Number": "Other",
            "undefined": "Dengue fever",
            "Claim-Final Diagnosis": "20 Nov 18",
            "Claim-Documents Received Date": "12 Oct 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Admission": "14 Oct 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Discharge": "APPROVED AND PAID",
            "Claim-Status": "12/11/2018",
            "Claim-Date Of Approval": "21",
            "Days": "187755",
            "Claim-Amount Claimed": "109876",
            "Claim-Sanctioned Amount": "62577",
            "Claim-Disallowed Amount": "NA",
            "Claim-Co-Payment Deduction": "FT",
            "Payment Mode": "11 Dec 18",
            "Claim-Cheque Date": "JUYGH98",
            "Claim-Cheque Number": "0",
            "Service Tax Rate": "181988",
            "TDS Rate": "0",
            "Claim-Service Tax Amt": "109961",
            "Claim-Date Of Last Query Sent": "IYT/9087",
            "Claim-Date Of Query Revert": "N"
        },
        {
            "Policy Number": "4106/151212/00/000",
            "Name Of The Insured": "NAGI REDDY",
            "Name Of The Self Member": "SELF",
            "Relationship": "IL1656",
            "Card Number/UHID": "113",
            "Member Reference No.": "34210",
            "Sum Assured": "CASHLESS",
            "Category Of Claim": "AL-5546",
            "AL-Inward Number": "3 Sep 18",
            "AL-Inward Date": "1108796",
            "AL-Number": "3 Sep 18",
            "AL-Expected Date Of Admission": "Other specified fever",
            "AL-Diagnosis": "APPROVED",
            "AL-Status": "59708",
            "AL-Sanction Date": "3 Sep 18",
            "AL-Copay Deduction": "Nizams Institute",
            "Claim-Hospital Name": "FRESH CLAIM",
            "Type Of Claim": "CL-0879",
            "Claim-Inward Number": "13 Oct 18",
            "Claim-Inward Date": "2012324",
            "Claim Number": "Infectious Diseases",
            "undefined": "O VARIAN CYSTECTOMY",
            "Claim-Final Diagnosis": "12 Oct 18",
            "Claim-Documents Received Date": "3 Sep 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Admission": "7 Sep 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Discharge": "APPROVED AND PAID",
            "Claim-Status": "12/14/2018",
            "Claim-Date Of Approval": "63",
            "Days": "77777",
            "Claim-Amount Claimed": "57002",
            "Claim-Sanctioned Amount": "3856",
            "Claim-Disallowed Amount": "NA",
            "Claim-Co-Payment Deduction": "FT",
            "Payment Mode": "14 Dec 18",
            "Claim-Cheque Date": "HUYU7677",
            "Claim-Cheque Number": "10.3",
            "Service Tax Rate": "10",
            "TDS Rate": "0",
            "Claim-Service Tax Amt": "5701",
            "Claim-TDS Amt": "87666",
            "Claim-Transferred Amt": "0",
            "Batch-Service Tax Amt": "5701",
            "Batch-TDS Amt": "51301",
            "DISEASE CODE": "IYT/9087",
            "NT CODE": "N"
        }
    ]
};
for (let i=4; i--;) excelrows.Sheet1=excelrows.Sheet1.concat(...excelrows.Sheet1)
// const excelrows=[...Array(1000)].map((_,i)=>["Row_"+i,i,i*i,i*i*i]);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
  data: { "excelRows": JSON.stringify(excelrows).replaceAll("],","],\n") },
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.excelRows).Sheet1.length);
  },
  error: function (data) {
    alert("fail");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, if you want so sent two-dimensional data it is recommended that you JSON encode them first.

Comment: Here is the sample data: Policy Number Name Of The Insured Name Of The Self Member Relationship Card Number/UHID Member Reference No. Sum Assured Category Of Claim AL-Inward Number AL-Inward Date AL-Number 40/759/00/0 ram KADAMBINI WIFE IL1600 698 250000 REIMBURSEMENT 40/759/00/000 SUCHITA SUCHITA SELF IL1640 1139 150000 REIMBURSEMENT 40/759/00/0 NAGI REDDY NAGI REDDY SELF IL16406 182 250000 CASHLESS AL-002515541 3 Sep 18 110200798500

Comment: When I am printing the data from PHP, the output is as below- Array ( [0] => Array ( [Policy Number] => 4016/152/00/000 [Name Of The Insured] => RAM [Name Of The Self Member] => KADAMBINI [Relationship] => WIFE [Category Of Claim] => REIMBURSEMENT [Claim-Hospital Name] => Nizams Institute [Type Of Claim] => FRESH CLAIM [Claim Number] => 2.2022E+11 [__EMPTY] => Other [Claim-Final Diagnosis] => leukaemia [Claim-Disallowed Reasons] => ~~~gate pass~diapers ) [1] => Array –

But i am not getting all the rows.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put the code into your original question, into a code segment, so we can see _exactly_, byte by byte what the data is.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to read an excel file using PHP, but due to some issues, I have read the file using javascript and sending the excel data (excelRows) to PHP using AJAX.
    From PHP, I need to insert the rows into MySQL.
    
    However,I am unable to get the complete data.
    excelRows contains 39 rows, but I am getting only 25 rows to PHP.

I have posted my code below.

Comment: @Pavani, in the first comment to this answer (after "Here is the data:") you pasted your "data", but unfortunately, as with everything that is entered here as a comment, it got "processed" in a way that tabs, new lines and other special characters were removed. What we need is the _original representation_ of the data either as a JSON-string or in a snippet as a JavaScript Object  or Array.

Comment: Hello Carsten, I have added the excel sample data as JSON.

Comment: Hello Carsten, 
It's working now after changing 
data: { "excelRows": (excelRows) }, to 
data: { "excelRows": JSON.stringify(excelRows).replaceAll("],","],\n") },

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- begin snippet-->
    
             <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <body>
            
                <h3>Choose an excel file to upload</h3>
            
                  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
                  <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="Upload()" >
             
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/jszip.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function Upload() {
                        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
                        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
                        if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
                            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                                var reader = new FileReader();
                                if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
                                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                                        ProcessExcel(e.target.result);
                                    };
                                    reader.readAsBinaryString(fileUpload.files[0]);
                                } else {
                                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                                        var data = "";
                                        var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                                        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
                                            data += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                                        }
                                        ProcessExcel(data);
                                    };
                                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileUpload.files[0]);
                                }
                            } else {
                                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
                            }
                        } else {
                            alert("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
                        }
                    };
                    function ProcessExcel(data) {
                        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                            type: 'binary'
                        });
                        var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];
                        var excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);
                 
                console.log(excelRows.length); <!-- output-39 -->
            
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "code.php",
                  data: { "excelRows": (excelRows) },
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                    alert("fail");
                  }
                });
                }
                </script>
                </body>
                </html>
    <!-- end snippet -->

code.php
        <?php
        $answer = $_POST ['excelRows'];
        print(count($answer)); -> output - 25
        $array = json_encode($answer); -> getting data in String format
        $data = json_decode($array, true); -> getting data in array format
        ?>
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to read an excel file using PHP, but due to some issues, I have read the file using javascript and sending the excel data (excelRows) to PHP using AJAX.
    From PHP, I need to insert the rows into MySQL.
    
    However,I am unable to get the complete data.
    excelRows contains 39 rows, but I am getting only 25 rows to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Sheet1": [
        {
            "Policy Number": "4106/151212/00/000",
            "Name Of The Insured": "RAM",
            "Name Of The Self Member": "KADAMBINI",
            "Relationship": "WIFE",
            "Card Number/UHID": "IL1666",
            "Member Reference No.": "444",
            "Sum Assured": "5455",
            "Category Of Claim": "REIMBURSEMENT",
            "Claim-Hospital Name": "OMNI Hospitals",
            "Type Of Claim": "FRESH CLAIM",
            "Claim-Inward Number": "CL-0123",
            "Claim-Inward Date": "29 Sep 18",
            "Claim Number": "278656",
            "undefined": "Other",
            "Claim-Final Diagnosis": "Myeloid leukaemia~Other septicaemia",
            "Claim-Documents Received Date": "28 Sep 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Admission": "2 Aug 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Discharge": "17 Aug 18",
            "Claim-Status": "APPROVED AND PAID",
            "Claim-Date Of Approval": "11/5/2018",
            "Days": "38",
            "Claim-Amount Claimed": "187765",
            "Claim-Sanctioned Amount": "420",
            "Claim-Disallowed Amount": "~~~gate pass~diapers",
            "Claim-Co-Payment Deduction": "FT",
            "Payment Mode": "5 Nov 18",
            "Claim-Cheque Date": "UYYY",
            "Claim-Cheque Number": "0",
            "Service Tax Rate": "888888",
            "TDS Rate": "0",
            "Claim-Service Tax Amt": "193399",
            "Batch-Service Tax Amt": "15 Oct 18",
            "Batch-TDS Amt": "23 Oct 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Query Revert": "N"
        },
        {
            "Policy Number": "4106/151212/00/000",
            "Name Of The Insured": "SUCHITA",
            "Name Of The Self Member": "SELF",
            "Relationship": "IL1640",
            "Card Number/UHID": "1342",
            "Member Reference No.": "333333",
            "Sum Assured": "REIMBURSEMENT",
            "AL-Copay Deduction": "Maxcure",
            "Claim-Hospital Name": "FRESH CLAIM",
            "Type Of Claim": "CL-09989",
            "Claim-Inward Number": "21 Nov 18",
            "Claim-Inward Date": "27865566",
            "Claim Number": "Other",
            "undefined": "Dengue fever",
            "Claim-Final Diagnosis": "20 Nov 18",
            "Claim-Documents Received Date": "12 Oct 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Admission": "14 Oct 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Discharge": "APPROVED AND PAID",
            "Claim-Status": "12/11/2018",
            "Claim-Date Of Approval": "21",
            "Days": "187755",
            "Claim-Amount Claimed": "109876",
            "Claim-Sanctioned Amount": "62577",
            "Claim-Disallowed Amount": "NA",
            "Claim-Co-Payment Deduction": "FT",
            "Payment Mode": "11 Dec 18",
            "Claim-Cheque Date": "JUYGH98",
            "Claim-Cheque Number": "0",
            "Service Tax Rate": "181988",
            "TDS Rate": "0",
            "Claim-Service Tax Amt": "109961",
            "Claim-Date Of Last Query Sent": "IYT/9087",
            "Claim-Date Of Query Revert": "N"
        },
        {
            "Policy Number": "4106/151212/00/000",
            "Name Of The Insured": "NAGI REDDY",
            "Name Of The Self Member": "SELF",
            "Relationship": "IL1656",
            "Card Number/UHID": "113",
            "Member Reference No.": "34210",
            "Sum Assured": "CASHLESS",
            "Category Of Claim": "AL-5546",
            "AL-Inward Number": "3 Sep 18",
            "AL-Inward Date": "1108796",
            "AL-Number": "3 Sep 18",
            "AL-Expected Date Of Admission": "Other specified fever",
            "AL-Diagnosis": "APPROVED",
            "AL-Status": "59708",
            "AL-Sanction Date": "3 Sep 18",
            "AL-Copay Deduction": "Nizams Institute",
            "Claim-Hospital Name": "FRESH CLAIM",
            "Type Of Claim": "CL-0879",
            "Claim-Inward Number": "13 Oct 18",
            "Claim-Inward Date": "2012324",
            "Claim Number": "Infectious Diseases",
            "undefined": "O VARIAN CYSTECTOMY",
            "Claim-Final Diagnosis": "12 Oct 18",
            "Claim-Documents Received Date": "3 Sep 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Admission": "7 Sep 18",
            "Claim-Date Of Discharge": "APPROVED AND PAID",
            "Claim-Status": "12/14/2018",
            "Claim-Date Of Approval": "63",
            "Days": "77777",
            "Claim-Amount Claimed": "57002",
            "Claim-Sanctioned Amount": "3856",
            "Claim-Disallowed Amount": "NA",
            "Claim-Co-Payment Deduction": "FT",
            "Payment Mode": "14 Dec 18",
            "Claim-Cheque Date": "HUYU7677",
            "Claim-Cheque Number": "10.3",
            "Service Tax Rate": "10",
            "TDS Rate": "0",
            "Claim-Service Tax Amt": "5701",
            "Claim-TDS Amt": "87666",
            "Claim-Transferred Amt": "0",
            "Batch-Service Tax Amt": "5701",
            "Batch-TDS Amt": "51301",
            "DISEASE CODE": "IYT/9087",
            "NT CODE": "N"
        }
    ]
}
```